# Stress-testing with artillery - Getting an auth0 bearer token using login flow

Tags: auth0, artillery

I want to use [artillery.io](https://artillery.io) as a stress-testing tool, and want to setup a basic stress-test. But all my url's are behind an auth wall (using Auth0) and I want to try to get a valid token for the testing session so that my backend does not throw me into a 401-spiral. The artillery docs explains that I can hook up to some lifecycle events using `processor`, but does not explain which lifecycle hooks I have available. I've managed to figure out that there is a `beforeRequest` hook I can use, but this does not seem optimal as this will probably run before every request. My tokens have at least an hour validity...

**So the main question is;** how do I construct a processor hook which taps into the auth0 login flow, retreives a token which can then be stored in an environment variable (or some other local mechanism) for use as an Authorization Bearer token in future requests done by artillery?

OR if this is a bad pattern to follow, what is the best practice for urls behind auth-walls? I've already thought about loging in first and then copying the token to an environment variable and use that, but this makes the test a bit harder to use since it requires a manual step.

Any input is greatly appreciated.